# C# Winforms Control.BeginInvoke with Action<T>

Tags: c#, winforms

Why can't method 1 be executed correctly, through Action <'string'> updateMsgAction, to add a message to the ListBox, but method 2 can be executed correctly?

I tried using method 3 [`BeginInvoke(Delegate, Object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=netframework-4.7#system-windows-forms-control-begininvoke(system-action))
, the compiler displays an error.

I want that method #2 can be like method #1 become a method to call when need update message.

**Method 1**: `UpdateMsg` using `Action<string>`

```
    private Action<string> updateMsgAction;

    public void UpdateMsg()
    {
        updateMsgAction = new Action<string>( (s) =>
        {
            MsgList.Items.Add(s);

            if (MsgList.Items.Count > 1000)
            {
                MsgList.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Method 3**: using `BeginInvoke(Delegate, Object[])`

```
    public delegate void MyDelegate(ListBox myControl, string myMessage);

    public void DelegateMethod(ListBox myControl, string myMsg)
    {
        myControl.Items.Add(myMsg);
    }
```

MQTT Server Start:

```
    public async void StartMqttServer()
    {
        try
        {
            var mqttFactory = new MqttFactory();

            if (mqttServer == null)
            {
                var mqttServerOptions = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder().WithDefaultEndpoint().WithDefaultEndpointPort(int.Parse(txtBoxPort.Text)).Build();
                mqttServer.ClientConnectedHandler = new MqttServerClientConnectedHandlerDelegate(OnMqttServerClientConnected);
                mqttServer.ClientDisconnectedHandler = new MqttServerClientDisconnectedHandlerDelegate(OnMqttServerClientDisconnected);
                mqttServer.ClientSubscribedTopicHandler = new MqttServerClientSubscribedTopicHandlerDelegate(OnMqttServerCleitnSubScribedTopic);
                mqttServer.ClientUnsubscribedTopicHandler = new MqttServerClientUnsubscribedTopicHandlerDelegate(OnMqttServerCleitnUnsubScribedTopic);
                mqttServer.ApplicationMessageReceivedHandler = new MqttApplicationMessageReceivedHandlerDelegate(OnMqttServerApplicationMessageReceived);
                await mqttServer.StartAsync(mqttServerOptions);

                MsgList.BeginInvoke(updateMsgAction, "MQTT Server is started."); //Method 1

                /*MsgList.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>((s) =>
                { MsgList.Items.Add(s); }), "MQTT Server is started."));*/ //Method 2

                //MsgList.BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(DelegateMethod), "MQTT Server is started.")); //Method 3
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MsgList.BeginInvoke(updateMsgAction, "MQTT Server start fail."));
        }
    }
```

OnMqttServerApplicationMessageReceived:

```
    public void OnMqttServerApplicationMessageReceived(MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
     // Method 1
     MsgList.BeginInvoke(updateMsgAction, 
       String.Format("Client[{0}]>> Topic:{1} Payload:{2} Qos:{3} Retain:{4}",
          e.ClientId, e.ApplicationMessage.Topic, e.ApplicationMessage.Payload.ToString(),
          e.ApplicationMessage.QualityOfServiceLevel, e.ApplicationMessage.Retain));
    }
```

Comment: When does this code call UpdateMsg()?  Never being a cause of whatever problem you forgot to describe.   An obvious way to get ahead is to avoid the variable and change the return type of UpdateMsg to `Action<string>`.

Comment: For this code, when await mqttServer.StartAsync after, show message in MsgList,
If used method 2, MsgList.BeginInvoke will need to be repeated several times

Comment: `async void` is *only* meant for asynchronous event handlers. Don't use it for anything else. You don't need `BeginInvoke` anyway. With `await` execution will go back to the UI thread without having to declare delegates, call `BeginInvoke` or check for completion. You could call `updateMsgAction()` directly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I update new code, If I need to print out the message when I receive it, but it BeginInvoke doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeginInvoke is used to execute some code in the thread in which the control was created. It's mandatory update controls in their own thread (usually in main thread) or you get an exception. So, your use or BeginInvoke is correct.

The problem is that, when you are running in the main thread and are be able to update the control, you delegate in an action the update. The action run in other thread and you are "cancelling" de BeginInvoke and getting the expected exception trying to update a control in other thread.

I use SynchronizationContext for this kind of things. In your form's code, add a variable:

```
private static SynchronizationContext Context;
```

**UPDATE: And initialize in the constructor:**

```
    public YourForm()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        // Other code
    }
```

Add this method:

```
private static void RunInMainThread(Action operation)
    {
        if (Context != SynchronizationContext.Current)
        {
            Context.Post(o => operation(), null);
        }
        else
        {
            operation();
        }
    }
```

If you already are running in main thread, your code run inmediatly. In other case, Post action run asynchronously in the main thread. You can use Send instead or Post to run synchronously. And use it when you need access to controls:

```
public void OnMqttServerApplicationMessageReceived(MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{    
   var msg = string.Format(
       "Client[{0}]>> Topic:{1} Payload:{2} Qos:{3} Retain:{4}",
       e.ClientId, 
       e.ApplicationMessage.Topic, 
       e.ApplicationMessage.Payload.ToString(),
       e.ApplicationMessage.QualityOfServiceLevel, 
       e.ApplicationMessage.Retain);

    RunInMainThread(() => 
    {
        MsgList.Items.Add(msg);
        // Other code...
    }
}
```

You can create an extension methods (Post and Send) for SynchronizationContext instead of RunInMainThread and reuse in your projects.

Comment: "cancelling" de BeginInvoke what this mean ?

Comment: It doesn't work....

Comment: "cancelling" refers that you use BeginInvoke to run in main thread but later you create an action that makes the code run in other thread. Really you aren't cancelling anything. That's why I used quotation marks

Comment: Are you creating your control (the form, the listctrl...) in the main thread? You only can update controls in the thread in which they was created. Check the thread in which you create the form

Comment: The problem was the initialization. I updated my response

Comment: My control existed in the form, the Listbox inside the tabControl.

Comment: When use SynchronizationContext need  initialization in the before use it ?

Comment: SynchronizationContext.Current always have a value. But the value is the current context. So, if you are in main thread and get the value of Current you get a context that it's different from Current that you get in other thread. So, in Form constructor, that you know is running in main thread, you save that context for later use.